# Mysqlbinlog statement reading

Tags: mysql, recovery, mysqlbinlog

I am trying to perform a point in time on a specific database using a snapshot and mysql's transaction logs. I am using the following to pull statements from the time of the snapshot to the time of recovery:

```
mysqlbinlog --database=**database** --start-datetime="$start_datetime" --stop-datetime="$stop_datetime" list_of_binlog_file_names
```

The resulting statements that mysqlbinlog produces include INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements for another database that has the form:

```
INSERT INTO **database**_reporting.tablename VALUES (data);
```

So functionally I'm getting statements from 2 different databases, one is our production database, the other is our reporting database, differentiated by nomenclature by the '_reporting'. It would appear to me that our application is inserting to the secondary database while still using the primary one and the binlogs associate both statements with the primary database.

Am I correct that mysqlbinlog is going to read out statements for both databases as long as they are executed after a `USE primary_database;`? Is there a way to separate out the ones for the reporting database using mysqlbinlog? I have searched quite a bit- I may be barking up the wrong tree here. Let me know if I can clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the [--database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_database) option does not screen out queries that explicitly name the database with the table, you should redirect that to grep and locate `primary_database` and INSERTs, UPDATEs, DELETEs:

```
mysqlbinlog --database=**database** --start-datetime="$start_datetime" --stop-datetime="$stop_datetime" list_of_binlog_file_names | grep "primary_database\." | grep "[IUD][NPE][SDL][EA][RT][TE]"
```

This may not be a perfect solution. Perhaps a good perl or python script and nail this one.

Comment: Conversely, the `--database` option will also fail to include queries against the specified database if a different database was the current database (via `USE`) when the query was run... it only matches the "current" database with statement-based logging.  With row-based logging, the `--database` flag works more as expected, but `mysqlbinlog` shows the actual rows changed, not the raw queries. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_database

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting the developers to fix their code, and grep -v to get rid of the unneeded stuff did the trick!